# How can I get one single unique data from Database for each one component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I have to get one unique record from mongoDB for every one single component. In my case: For component 1 I want to get 1st document from database, for component 2 I want to get 2nd document.. etc till 16th.

The code :

```
router.get('/:name', (res, req) => {
 Buttons.findOne()
sort({name : 1})
.then(buttons => res.json(buttons))
});
```

and the code of function :

```
  async function getButtons() {
try {
const response = await axios.get('api/buttons/:name');
console.log(response);
catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to send requests with variables you need to do like below

```
async function getButtons(name) {
     try {
        const response = await axios.get('api/buttons/'+name);
        console.log(response);
     }
     catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
     }
}
```

or

```
async function getButtons(name) {
     try {
        const response = await axios.get(`api/buttons/${name}`);
        console.log(response);
     }
     catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
     }
}
```

> pass your component count in getButtons(count)

> when send request add your variable to url

Comment: Hi! Thanks for an answer but sadly thats not working too good for me. I think we missunderstood. I generate 16 requests now because I use this request in component which is used 16 times and it works okay, but I wanted to make it give me 16 different records from database. For now I have first record displayed in console.log 16times which is bad because I want to assign the data from database to frontend